# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined at quote.min.js:2

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.3.3

Magento 2.3.3

Installation of Clearpay payment plugin.

On completion of checkout, user is returned to an empty shopping cart rather than order confirmation page.  Order is recored in backend and order confirmation emails are sent.

Nothing in logs but following error in Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined
at quote.min.js:2
at Object.execCb (10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:112)
at Module.check (10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:56)
at Module.<anonymous> (10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:72)
at 10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:11
at 10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:74
at each (10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:3)
at Module.emit (10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:74)
at Module.check (10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:61)
at Module.enable (10b3c252f72fe3679fe8c8942cf02279.min.js:73)
```

Other payment options work fine.

Unbundled / unminified js, but issue still present; although doing so narrowed issue down to

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined
    at quote.js:33
```

which is

```
var proceedTotalsData = function (data) {
            if (_.isObject(data) && _.isObject(data['extension_attributes'])) {
                _.each(data['extension_attributes'], function (element, index) {
                    data[index] = element;
                });
            }

            return data;
        },
        billingAddress = ko.observable(null),
        shippingAddress = ko.observable(null),
        shippingMethod = ko.observable(null),
        paymentMethod = ko.observable(null),
        **quoteData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteData,**        
        basePriceFormat = window.checkoutConfig.basePriceFormat,
        priceFormat = window.checkoutConfig.priceFormat,
        storeCode = window.checkoutConfig.storeCode,
        totalsData = proceedTotalsData(window.checkoutConfig.totalsData),
        totals = ko.observable(totalsData),
        collectedTotals = ko.observable({});
```

What is causing the problem and what is the solution here?